# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: hello.html

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

My project structure is as below :

```
flask-blog/      
    application.py          
    templates/         
        home.html
```

My templates folder is also correctly named. I don't understand where the issue is!

```
File "C:\Users\Aswathi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
  return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)  

File "C:\project\application.py", line 6, in hello
  return render_template('hello.html')

File "C:\Users\Aswathi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 134, in render_template
  return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),

File "C:\Users\Aswathi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
  return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)

File "C:\Users\Aswathi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 830, in get_template
  return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))

File "C:\Users\Aswathi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
  template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)

File "C:\Users\Aswathi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 113, in load
  source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)

File "C:\Users\Aswathi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 58, in get_source
  return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)

File "C:\Users\Aswathi\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 86, in _get_source_fast
  raise TemplateNotFound(template)
```

jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: hello.html

Comment: Please describe the issue in your case...

Comment: I am getting the above error. Template not found.

Comment: I mean the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask raises TemplateNotFound error even though template file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327293/flask-raises-templatenotfound-error-even-though-template-file-exists)

Comment: Oh, I am not able to paste the complete stack trace in the comments section. So I uninstalled flask and installed again using pip, just to try. But now it is giving me error ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask'. When I go to install it says requirement satisfied! Ugh

Comment: Provide a stacktrace for `ImportError` you are getting... Are you running that as a python script?

Comment: That importError is resolved. But again, the previous error exists even after installing flask again! Still says TemplateNotFound.

Comment: I have edited my question and included the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

always save html files in **templates** folder

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the template hello.html, but the only template you have in your templates directory is home.html

Answer (score 0):

Passing `home` in `render_template` instead of `home.html` worked for me

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('home')
```