# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: register.html

Tags: python, flask

I try to display my html form in flask , but i get this error:jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound:  register.html

I show the question here:
[Flask raises TemplateNotFound error even though template file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327293/flask-raises-templatenotfound-error-even-though-template-file-exists)

But **i** **have already created a file name templates**

```
/myproject
    app.py
    templates/
        register.html
```

My app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request

@app.route('/enternew')
def new_register():
       return render_template(' register.html')
```

My register.html

```
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "{{ url_for('geodata') }}" method = "POST">
         <h3>Form </h3>
         name<br>
         <input type = "text" name = "name" /></br>

         lot<br>
         <textarea name = "lot" ></textarea><br>

         lan<br>
         <input type = "text" name = "lan" /><br>


         <input type = "submit" value = "submit" /><br>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Any possible answers? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the extra space you have before the 'register.html':

```
return render_template(' register.html')
```