# Flask raises "TemplateNotFound" even though "templates/" is in the Same Directory

Tags: python, templates, flask, path

I am following this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask#_use-a-template-to-render-a-page.)
.
Similar to [Flask raises TemplateNotFound error even though template file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327293/flask-raises-templatenotfound-error-even-though-template-file-exists)  from six years ago, I cannot render the page because Flask raises "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: hello_there.html". Not only is `hello_there.html` in the `templates` directory, I believe `templates` is located in the right place because it's in the same directory as the Python module (outside the virtual environment):

```
hello_flask/
    env/
        app.py
    templates/
        hello_there.html
```

From that same [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327293/flask-raises-templatenotfound-error-even-though-template-file-exists), I tried setting the `EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING` option to `True`, but I didn't get a report logged to the Flask `app.logger` if I configured it correctly in `launch.json`:

```
"env": {
            "FLASK_APP": "app.py",
            "FLASK_ENV": "development",
            "EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING": "True",
            "FLASK_DEBUG": "0"
        }
```

Okay, finally, when I run the program through the Flask debug configuration, it raises `FileNotFoundError`, "The system cannot find the path specified". Would this affect the template error? I have run a basic python Flask file fine without templates even with this error. I've tried to fix it by adding the location of the interpret to the `PATH` variable which I copied from a `sys.executable` print statement, but the interpreter still raises it.

Comment: `app.py` should not be in the `env` directory. Move it in the upper directory next to `templates`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the `app.py` file and templates folder in the same directory. Also you can explicitly mention the templates folder name.

In your app.py;

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
```