# TemplateNotFound even though I can print out the directory

Tags: python, flask

I am adding a swaggerUI to a Flask API. I have my app and inside the app I created a swagger dir where the templates live. I set the template_folder when the flask app is initialized in the `__init__` file. This appears to be working since it prints out the correct directory inside the function. I even did an ls and the swaggerui.html file is there, but I am still getting and error that the template is not found. Also, if I add a random file testin123.txt in the templates_folder, when I refresh the site, testing123.txt prints out. What am I missing?

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template, Blueprint
from flask import current_app as current_app
import os

docs = Blueprint('docs', __name__)

@docs.route('/docs')
def get_docs():
    #this prints out the correct path
    print(f"template dir is {current_app.template_folder}")
    
    #this prints "swaggerui.html"
    for filename in os.listdir(current_app.template_folder):
        print(filename)

    print("After ls")
    
    #even though everything check-out still cant find file
    return render_template('swaggerui.html')
```

```
template dir is flask_project/swagger/templates/

swaggerui.html

test123.txt

After ls
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/app/./flask_project/docs.py", line 28, in get_docs
    return render_template('swaggerui.html')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 148, in render_template
    ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1068, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 997, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 958, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 125, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 59, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 95, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: swaggerui.html
```

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── docs.py
├── swagger
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── swagger-ui.css
│   │   ├── img
│   │   │   ├── favicon-16x16.png
│   │   │   └── favicon-32x32.png
│   │   ├── js
│   │   │   ├── swagger-ui-bundle.js
│   │   │   ├── swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js
│   │   │   └── swagger-ui.js
│   │   └── openapi.json
│   └── templates
│   └── swaggerui.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set [EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/#EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING) option in your app and past the output here.

```
myApp = Flask(__name__)
myApp.config["EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING"] = True
```

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327293/flask-raises-templatenotfound-error-even-though-template-file-exists/56589998#56589998) too