# TemplateNotFound jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: login.html

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller, python-standalone

this the error which is occurring after the code is converted to exe file

[the error exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPkKM.png)
[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LICpg.png)

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flask\app.py", line 2213, in _call_
  File "flask\app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app
  File "flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
  File "flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
  File "flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
  File "flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
  File "app.py", line 122, in login
  File "flask\templating.py", line 150, in render_template
  File "jinja2\environment.py", line 1081, in get_or_select_template
  File "jinja2\environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
  File "jinja2\environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
  File "jinja2\loaders.py", line 126, in load
  File "flask\templating.py", line 64, in get_source
  File "flask\templating.py", line 98, in _get_source_fast
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: login.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `--add-data` flag to your pyinstaller command with the path to the templates folder as the argument.

For example:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "./templates;./templates" app.py
```

Use `:` as the path separator if you are using linux of mac.

Comment: ya after adding the --add-data worked thank you..

Answer (score 0):

The error thrown here simply means that `Jinja` is unable to locate `login.html`. Ensure the `templates/` folder contains the `login.html` file as the `render_template(<path_to_file>)` will look for it in the `templates` folder.

Note: Please do not share screenshots of code, rather snippets of code will help better.

To understand further and debug better: [Flask raises TemplateNotFound error even though template file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327293/flask-raises-templatenotfound-error-even-though-template-file-exists)

Comment: the templets folder contains the login.html but its giving tis exception

Comment: To understand further and debug better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327293/flask-raises-templatenotfound-error-even-though-template-file-exists